# labeling image with different colors

Tags: image, matlab, label

I  am using the connected component labeling algorithm in Matlab. Is it possible to use different color for different labels when showing the output? (Even though the labels have the same intensity).

**Clarification:**
I used connected component labeling algorithm to label the connected components of a binary images. Now I got different labels. All the labels contains pixel of equal intensity. (All the labels have pixel intensity value of 1) and all the labels appear in the same color. I want to display the different labels using different colors so that I can eliminate the unwanted one easier.

Comment: More clarification is required...

Comment: I used connected component labeling algorithm to label the connected components of a binary images. Now i got different labels. All the labels contains pixel of equal intensity. (All the labels have pixel intensity value of 1)  and all the labels appear in the same color. I want to display the different labels using different colors so that i can eliminate the unwanted one easier...Let me know if u still need clarification on this question..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is easy - use the `imagesc` function:

```
p = imread('peppers.png'); %Read image
b = (p(:,:,2)>100); % Thresholding by some constant threshold
```

If you already have a binary image, just use this section of the code: (`b` is the image)

```
L = bwlabel(b); %Find components
figure();   %Create figure
imagesc(L);  %Draw the components, each in its own color.
```

[image]

You can also change the colors by using the `colormap` command:

```
 colormap(bone)
```

[image]

In order to customize the colors, define an `nx3` matrix, and give it as input to `colormap`

```
cm = [1 0 0; 
      0 1 0; 
      0 0 1
      0 1 1 
      1 1 0
    ];
colormap(cm)
```

Comment: I mentioned that it was a binary image. I have groups of white pixels scattered in the image. I want to label those groups with different colors.. Hope you clarify me

Comment: for 3D images you also can use "bwlabeln"